# How many .htaccess files should a Wordpress multisite (subdirectory set up) have?

Tags: multisite, htaccess

We have a multsite subdirectory site with two sites.  We set this up several years ago and everything has been working correctly until recently.  One thing I'm trying to find out is how many htaccess files there *should* be in the whole directory structure.  We currently have two; one at the root of the directory and one inside of the wordpress folder.  Are both needed?  If not, which one is not needed?  Thank you.

Comment: is the root of your directory your `htdoc`/`public_html` folder? I'm not sure there is a canonical correct answer other than "does it work or not" that can be given here. What is the concern? Have you tried removing one to test then restoring it to see if it's necessary? Only you can answer wether both are necessary or not via testing, especially when we don't know how your site and server are structured and the contents of the files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.